# Emmet.vim – Is it possible to set "title" attribute in a link?

Tags: vim, plugins

Is it (and if yes how is it) possible to get the following code by using the great Emmet.vim plugin:

```
<a class="myclass" title="mytitle" href=""> ... </a>
```

Just to remember with:

```
a.myclass
```

you'll get:

```
<a class="myclass" href=""> ... </a>
```

The [source tutorial](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim/blob/master/TUTORIAL) doesn't answer the question. Google also not seems to be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it works in Emmet but in Sparkup, I would do:

```
a.myclass[title=mytitle][href=]
```